# Multiple @ rule functions concatenated with a comma

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to have some custom rules for firefox, and up until now I used
`@-moz-document url-prefix()`
But according to the docs `@-moz-document`will not be supported in future versions.
Instead `@document` will be supported.

So I changed from this:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
   ...
}
```

To this

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(),
@document url-prefix() {
   ...
}
```

But for some reason now, the rules no longer apply

Answer (score 1):

The reason this won't work is that chained CSS selectors/directives are evaluated as one.
If one of the parts fails evaluation the entire style is disregarded

Example:

```
//  
[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb, [type="range"]::-ms-thumb { ... }
                 makes IE skip             makes Firefox skip

// 
[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb { ... }    makes IE skip (Firefox will work) 
[type="range"]::-ms-thumb { ... }           makes Mozilla skip (IE will work)
```

In your case current Firefox will understand @-moz-document url-prefix() but not @document url-prefix() causing it to skip the style.

Therefore when dealing with vendor specific implementations always keep your styles separated.

I hope it made sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

From [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document):

> From version 61: this feature is behind the
>   layout.css.moz-document.content.enabled preference (needs to be set to
>   true). To change preferences in Firefox, visit about:config.

Comment: But notice I don't want the rule to be enabled just on my end, I want the client (with whatever firefox version he uses) to have that rule

Comment: What you're saying is that you don't want this to be an experimental technology.  There is no way around that at this point in time.  According to MDN, this is currently a Firefox-only, opt-in feature.  You have no control over the user's browser prefs.  In short, this technology is not ready for production and available only to you as a developer who knows to opt in specifically with the FF browser.